# How to assign Elastic IP to Application Load Balancer in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I created an Application Load Balancer in AWS.

How can I assign an Elastic IP address to the application load balancer? I didn't find any IP address in the load balancer description.

Comment: Balancers scale out, in, up, and down, so are typically accessed by hostame, because the IP addresses are not static.  What problem are you trying to solve with an EIP?  Are you trying to configure DNS?  Or do you have a situation requiring a static address?

Comment: One of the biggest problems with ALB is white listing it's auto-generated IPs. Also, as John Rotenstein stated below, the only solution so far is to use a NLB in front of ALB

Answer (score 21):

An Application Load Balancer cannot be assigned an Elastic IP address (static IP address).

However, a Network Load Balancer can be assigned one Elastic IP address for each Availability Zone it uses.

If you do not wish to use a Network Load Balancer, you can combine the two by putting the Network Load Balancer in front of the Application Load Balancer:

[image: NLB in front of ALB]

See: [Using static IP addresses for Application Load Balancers | Networking & Content Delivery](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/using-static-ip-addresses-for-application-load-balancers/)

Comment: Now superseded by https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/09/application-load-balancer-aws-privatelink-static-ip-addresses-network-load-balancer ?

Answer (score 10):

You can now get global static IPs for your Application Load Balancer directly from the Load Balancer Management Console, either in the creation wizard or in the Integrated services tab. See [this blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/improving-availability-and-performance-for-application-load-balancers-using-one-click-integration-with-aws-global-accelerator/).

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use AWS Global Accelerator: 
[AWS Global Accelerator](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/using-bring-your-own-ip-addresses-byoip-with-global-accelerator/)

However, it's probably going to be more expensive than using NLB - ALB architecture.