# AWS ELB ip address

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

Is there a way to assign ipv4 address to Load Balancer in EC2 , just like we assign Elastic IP address to EC2 instances. If not, how can I get the IP address of ELB. I need to give the ip address of Load Balancer to an external application so that ELB can receive requests.So I don't want the IP address of ELB to be changed often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Application Load Balancer does not have a static IP address. It should always be referenced via DNS Name.

However, a **Network Load Balancer** is given a static IP address for each AZ to which it is connected. If a Network Load Balancer is not suitable, then a Network Load Balancer can be placed in front of an Application Load Balancer.

See: [How to assign Elastic IP to Application Load Balancer in AWS? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55236806/how-to-assign-elastic-ip-to-application-load-balancer-in-aws/55243777#55243777)

Comment: Thanks a lot, what is AZ that you are referring to?

Comment: When a load balancer is created, you must nominate the AZs to which it connects.

Comment: Do NLB and ALB work well for SIP (protocol based) load balancing as well right?

Comment: @Vineel Not sure. I don't think it will work with ALB, so try it with an NLB.

Comment: It is a UDP based protocol. I 'm under the impression that only TCP based protocols are supported.